# Reusable function to avoid repeating prop name with React Storybook's Knob plugin?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm using React Storybook. Any time that I pass a prop to a component I want it be editable with the Knob plugin:

```
storiesOf("ComponentA", module).add("default", () => (
    <ComponentA foo={object("foo", 100)} />
));

storiesOf("ComponentB", module).add("default", () => (
    <ComponentB bar={object("bar", false)} />
));
```

The code above works but I have to repeat the prop name eg "foo" and "bar". Is it possible to mare a reusable function to avoid this?

I tried the following but calling the `editableProps` function results in an error, even if its not spread into the React component

```
const editableProps = (propName, propValue) => {
    return { [propName]: object(propName, propValue) };
};

storiesOf("ComponentA", module).add("default", () => (
    <ComponentA {...editableProps('foo', 100)} />
));
```

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `knob.value` supplied to
>   `ObjectType`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the nicest syntax but Ive got something working:

```
import { text, number } from "@storybook/addon-knobs/react";

const editableProps = (name, value) => {
  const types = {
    string: text,
    number
  };
  const type = types[typeof value];
  return {
    [name]: type(name, value)
  };
}

storiesOf("ComponentA", module).add("default", () => (
  <ComponentA {...editableProps("foo", 100)} />
));
storiesOf("ComponentB", module).add("default", () => (
  <ComponentB {...editableProps("text", "Im a string")} />
));
```